# Run a single TestNG test case (TestClass.method) from the command line

Tags: java, testng

I'm trying to build a shell script that will let me specify a classname and method name as parameters, and invoke just that one test case using TestNG.

I've built a script that lets me run a single group, which works, and it looks like this:

```
JAR=`(cd target && ls -1 test-*-jar-with-dependencies.jar)`
java \
  -jar target/$JAR \
  -testjar target/$JAR \
  -xmlpathinjar testng.xml \
  -groups [GROUP-NAME] \
  -excludegroups not-implemented,broken,manual
```

The `.jar` file referenced above was built using `mvn package` using the `maven-assembly-plugin` with `<mainClass>org.testng.TestNG</mainClass>`, and it works just fine for executing a whole group of tests.

I want to change `-groups` to run a single test case, one method within a single test class.  Looking at the [docs](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html), I've tried the following:

```
JAR=`(cd target && ls -1 test-*-jar-with-dependencies.jar)`
java \
  -jar target/$JAR \
  -testjar target/$JAR \
  -xmlpathinjar testng.xml \
  -methods [CLASS.METHOD]
```

This just attempts to run everything.  Reading between the lines, it sounds like if there is a `testng.xml` file, the `-methods` parameter might be ignored, so I tried:

```
JAR=`(cd target && ls -1 test-*-jar-with-dependencies.jar)`
java \
  -jar target/$JAR \
  -testname "Run Single Test" \
  -methods [CLASS.METHOD]
```

At first, I thought this worked.  But instead of running the single test method and then stopping, it ran it over and over again.  I didn't let it run to see how many times it ran it, but I'm guessing that if allowed, it would have executed it once for every test case in the code base.

I'm currently running Java 1.8.0_111, TestNG 6.14.3.  Is this a bug in TestNG, or am I not passing the correct command-line parameters?

Comment: Can you show your test class?

Comment: As per testng documentation `-methods  A comma separated list of fully qualified class name and method`. For example `com.example.Foo.f1,com.example.Bar.f2.` so make sure you are providing fully qualified name of method. For instance     -methods PKG.CLASS.METHOD

Comment: Yes, I tested with fully qualified class.method name.  And it ran the method in question.  It just runs it over and over again.

Comment: @AndiCover, I have hundreds of test classes.  They all work fine when running by the group.  But when I try to re-run a failed test from the command-line, that's when I see this anomalous behavior.